# How to call a Function in a python

Tags: python, function, nested

There is a function **def on_ticks(ws,ticks)** and what this function does is gets the ticks value of the stocks from market:

```
def on_ticks(ws,ticks):
    for tick in ticks:
    data = tick  # all the incoming tick data stored in variable data.
```

Now i need to create some strategy and i define a new function for the strategy **def calculate_orb()**

```
def calculate_orb():
```

Since in this function i need the tick data from the function **on_ticks**, so i need to know how to call **on_ticks** function in the calculate_orb() function so that i can make my calculation according to the tick data received from market

so the complete code would look like below:

```
def on_ticks(ws,ticks):
    for tick in ticks:
    data = tick 

def calculate_orb():
    on_ticks()
```

Comment: What is your question? It's not clear what you want to do. Do you want to retrieve the data from `on_ticks`?

Comment: Do you want to get every next tick from the loop from `on_ticks()` in your `calculate_orb()`?

Comment: Or you want to get the full array of ticks?

Comment: `data = tick` is ultimately doing just `data = ticks[-1]`. You are wasting every other values.

Comment: This code has neither a `main` or even `return`  values... Come on.

Comment: @QuantumLicht yes i want to retrieve the data from on_ticks in function calculate_orb  and with that data i would like to do further calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Try consuming the return values of your on_ticks() function into your calculate_orb funtion:

```
def on_ticks(ws,ticks):
    for tick in ticks:
        data = tick 

def calculate_orb():
    for data in on_ticks(value_for_ws, value_for_ticks):
        # TODO
```

Comment: If you want to consume, there should be something that the function has to return.